# Is a core dump possible when compiling a single file and linking with other .o files?

Tags: c++, linker

I am currently working with a project with many C++ files. All C++ files were working fine previously.

I made a change to one file named `a.cpp`.

When I do this, I usually compile `a.cpp` and get `a.o`, then I link all the `.o` files to create the executable.  This usually works.

Today, however, a core dump occurred in the file I changed.

After recompiling everything, it worked fine.

What caused this?

NOTE: There is no dynamic library call.

Comment: What is your compiler? What command line parameters are you passing to it? By the `exe` tag, I'm assuming that you're on Windows, but which version?

Answer (score 4):

If you get a core dump after an incremental build and the program works after a full build, this usually means that your object files were compiled against different versions of a header file.

For example, suppose that `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` are using the following structure:

```
struct SampleStruct {
  char *SampleString;
};
```

Now suppose the structure is changed and only `a.cpp` is recompiled:

```
struct SampleStruct {
  int SampleInt;
  char *SampleString;
};
```

Whenever `a.o` looks at a SampleStruct, it will expect an int at offset 0 and a char pointer at offset 4.  Whenever `b.o` looks at a SampleStruct, it will expect a char pointer at offset 0, so if `a.o` gives `b.o` a SampleStruct, `b.o` will try to treat an int as a char pointer.  Chaos ensues.

The solution is to use a proper build system that can pick up header dependencies.  For example, if you're using Make, you can use something like the [GenericMakefile](https://github.com/mbcrawfo/GenericMakefile) to have Make and GCC track header dependencies for you.